# Pip install raises UnicodeDecodeError on Windows. Fix?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pip

When trying to install mysql-python on my Windows 10 machine i get the following error:

```
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\LUCAFL~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-3u7aih0l\mysql-python\setup.py", line 21, in <module>
    setuptools.setup(**metadata)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  ...
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1055, in communicate
    stdout = self.stdout.read()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python35-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1716: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried installing other packages and received the same error on almost every one (one exception being pymysql). All of these packages were big and had dependencies. I guess that the big ones create temporary data in my user directories APPDATA folder. As you can see, the **ü** is not properly decoded (ü being byte 0x81). It's always a german umlaut that produces the error (mainly ü, as it's part of my user folders name).

I googled for the last 2 hours and found a lot of people having the same problem, but mostly they were opening github tickets or discussing the problem for Ubuntu/Fedora/OSX, etc. A couple times i read, that the standard encoding under windows is cp-1252 which causes the problem. Can i somehow force windows using my console to use utf-8 for this session and then run pip with that?

Please don't recommend me renaming my user folder. It's not easily done under Windows 10 and i dont want to re-install windows just because of python.

My setup: Windows 10, Python 3.5.1, pip 8.0.3

Comment: `distutils._msvccompiler._get_vc_env` uses the subprocess module to call `vcvarsall.bat` and `set` to get the environment. cmd.exe built-in commands such as `set` default to using the current console codepage when `stdout` is a pipe, which in your case is the OEM codepage, 850. But with `universal_newlines=True` subprocess decodes the output using the ANSI codepage, which in your case is 1252. As a quick fix first run `chcp.com 1252` to change the console codepage.

Comment: The best option for distutils here would be to call `subprocess.Popen` directly to run `cmd.exe /U /c`, which makes the built-in `set` command output UTF-16LE text. Then read the output from `stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(proc.stdout, encoding='utf-16le')`. This way you get the exact Unicode environment instead of potentially mangling it through an ANSI or OEM codepage conversion.

Comment: This seems to fix the decoding problem. I am still a little bit confused, why changing the codepage fixes the problem. I thought it was a UnicodeDecodeError?

Comment: The `universal_newlines` option of `subprocess.Popen` wraps the child process `stdout` stream with an `io.TextIOWrapper` that decodes the stream using the platform's preferred encoding, which is the ANSI codepage on Windows. But cmd.exe is encoding the output of  the `set` command using the console codepage, which defaults to the OEM codepage, 850. In codepage 850 "ü" is `b'\x81'`, which isn't mapped by codepage 1252 -- hence the decode error.

Comment: Getting the environment converted to either codepage 850 or 1252 is really hideous. The environment is Unicode and the filesystem is Unicode, so the relevant paths from environment variables, especially when a user name is involved, may not be encodable in either the OEM or ANSI codepage. In your case ANSI works, but I've seen more than a few cases in terms of bug reports where using Unicode strictly from start to finish is required. It's 2016 and we're still stuck messing around with code pages from the 80s and early 90s pre-Unicode era. That's just sad.

Comment: I was thinking the same reading through your comments. Just using a single encoding would save a lot of pain.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following and see if it works. Replace path for python by your actual path.
I am not able to simulate on my windows laptop.

```
import sys
import subprocess

reload(sys)  # Reload may do the trick!
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')


theproc =subprocess.call(['C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\pip.exe', 'install', 'mysql-python'])
theproc.communicate()
```

Comment: I googled around a bit and besides presenting another problem of possibly breaking code that depends on the standard ascii encoding, the sys.setdefaultencoding hack was removed in python 3.

Comment: you can use `reload(sys)`  on last line again . This will reload default system parameters before executing next set of code and thus hopefully will prevent any breaking.  We are trying to use it just for `pip install` section.

Comment: With code depending on ascii i meant the installation process as a whole (whatever happens in there). This approach still doesnt work with python3.x, sys.setdefaultencoding will stay deleted, even when calling imp.reload.